# Google Tag Manager Custom JavaScript Parse Error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a Custom JavaScript GTM variable.

But it keeps telling me I have a parse error...

`Error at line 4, character 53: Parse error. ')' expected`

But I can't see the problem. Any ideas whats wrong?

```js
function() {
  var clickclasses = "{{Click Classes}}";
  if (clickclasses.includes("download-color-wheel") {
    return "Downloaded Color Wheel";
  }
  if (clickclasses.includes("lp-10%-coupon") {
    return "Claimed 10pct Coupon on Landing Page";
  }
  if (clickclasses.includes("exit-popup-10%-coupon") {
    return "Claimed 10pct Coupon on Exit Popup";
  }
  if (clickclasses.includes("video-testimonial-submitted") {
    return "Video Testimonial Submitted";
  }
  return "Clicked";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing brackets for if statements are missing.

Updated code:

```
function() {
  var clickclasses = "{{Click Classes}}";
  if (clickclasses.includes("download-color-wheel")) {
    return "Downloaded Color Wheel";
  }
  if (clickclasses.includes("lp-10%-coupon")) {
    return "Claimed 10pct Coupon on Landing Page";
  }
  if (clickclasses.includes("exit-popup-10%-coupon")) {
    return "Claimed 10pct Coupon on Exit Popup";
  }
  if (clickclasses.includes("video-testimonial-submitted")) {
    return "Video Testimonial Submitted";
  }
  return "Clicked";
}
```

Comment: your answer was correct.please elaborate more and post the corrected code as well.

Comment: Yes sorry but I'm confused, could you post the correct code to help me see it?